# how to remove an object from my razor view after clicking on the delete link

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

i have the following view inside my asp.net MVC :-

```
 @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr >

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserID)
                    <td id ="userclass">
                  @Ajax.ActionLink("Add User to Class",
     "Register", "User",
    new { id = item.UserID, classid = ViewBag.id },

    new AjaxOptions { 

        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        UpdateTargetId = "incrementadd",
        LoadingElementId = "progressToadd",
OnSuccess = "removerow"


})
 </td>
```

i need to remove the table row that contains the object that was added; i tried to define `onsuccess"removerow"` inside the above ajax link with the following script , but it did not work out:-

```
function removerow() {

    jAlert('The Answer was added succsfully', 'Add Confirmation');

    var self = this;
    $(self).remove();
    });}
```

so how i can achieve this ?
BR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a bit weird as you are talking about deleting a row and showing us code about adding classes. Then you talk about a `removerow` callback. Things are not really related in your question. But anyway, 2 possibilities come to mind:

1. Have the controller action that you are calling with AJAX to delete the answer return a partial view containing the table and then replace the table in the success callback with this partial.
2. Remove the corresponding row on the client in the success callback

The drawback of the first approach is that you need to perform an additional SQL query to refetch the dataset that allowed you to initially generate the table but ensures that you will get correct data. With the second approach if you only remove the corresponding row using javascript, there might be other users that have deleted other rows on the same time and you won't get a correct representation of the data.

So in the first approach you externalize the table into a partial:

```
<div id="incrementadd">
    @Html.Partial("_Table", Model.Answers)
</div>
```

and then in your Delete action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    1. Delete the record with the given id in your database
    2. Refetch all the answers and pass them to the partial

    return PartialView("_Table", answers);
}
```

With the second approach you must pass to the success callback the current row of the table to be removed. For this you could assign it an unique id on the `<tr>` element:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
    <tr id="row@item.ID">
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserID)
        </td>
        <td id ="userclass">
            @Ajax.ActionLink(
                "Delete answer",
                "Delete", 
                "Answers",
                new { 
                    id = item.ID, 
                },
                new AjaxOptions { 
                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                    OnSuccess = string.Format(
                        "deleteSuccess({0})", 
                        Json.Encode(item.ID)
                    ),
                    LoadingElementId = "progressToadd"
                }
            )
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

and the `deleteSuccess`:

```
var deleteSuccess = function(rowid) {
     $('#row' + rowid).remove();
};
```

Comment: sorry for the inconsistency , i have edited my question to include the correct code. what i am trying to do is to remove the object that was added and not deleted.

Comment: it worked fine; but should i use @row when i define the ID for the table row? as i tried the following <tr id = "@item.ID" > and it worked fine. so what are the differences between using tr id="row@item.ID"> <tr id = "@item.ID" >

Comment: It will depend what format are those ids. If they are numbers, if you use `id="123"` you will get invalid HTML as ids cannot start with a number whereas id="row123" ensures that you get valid HTML.

Comment: but on some views inside my application i use something like <tr id =  @answer.AnswersID> and it works fine, although the answer ID will have values such as "123" as it is an indentity integer...